# How to get pygmentize CLI to use the Python3 lexers?

Tags: pygments, pygmentize

I'm having a problem debugging and issue lexing of a language using Python3 and pygments. I had the setup working with Python2 but failing to combine it correctly for Python3.

MY primary question is how do I get the CLI `pygmentize` to use the Python3 lexers. It seems to always use the Python2 installed lexers. I also don't see that `pygmentize` is actually part of the `pygments` package (so I might be confused on how that's actually installed).

*Note: I have the lexer installed in 3, and rebuilding the mapfiles shows that it is recognized, but when I use the markdown `codehilite` extension it doesn't find the lexer it seems. I want to run the CLI pygmentize to try and debug what the problem is.*